# read multiple csv files with the same column headings and find the mean

Tags: r, csv, mean

Is it possible to read multiple csv excell files into R. All of the csv files have the same 4 columns. the first is a character, the second and third are numeric and the fourth is integer. I want to combine the data in each numeric column and find the mean.

I can get the csv files into R with

```
data <- list.files(directory)
myFiles <- paste(directory,data[id],sep="/")
```

I am unable to get the numbers from the individual columns add them and find the mean.

I am completely new to R and any advice is appreciated.

Comment: from my experience, you need to add line data[,3:4] <- as.numeric(data[,3:4]).

Comment: This question has been asked multiple times. Please do some searching.

Comment: That code does not read data into R. Try `?read.csv`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple method:

Prep: Generate dummy data: (You already have this)

```
dummy <- data.frame(names=rep("a",4), a=1:4,b=5:8)

write.csv(dummy,file="data01.csv",row.names=F)
write.csv(dummy,file="data02.csv",row.names=F)
write.csv(dummy,file="data03.csv",row.names=F)
```

Step0: Load the file names: (just like you are doing)

```
data <- dir(getwd(),".csv")
```

Step1: Read and combine:

```
DF <- do.call(rbind,lapply(data,function(fn) read.csv(file=fn,header=T)))
DF
```

Step2: Find mean of appropriate columns:

```
apply(DF[,2:3],2,mean)
```

Hope that helps!!

EDIT: If you are having trouble with file path, try `?file.path`.